# how to change module xml params in front end

Tags: joomla

Do not bother
I am using a Joomla weather module. In this module the administrator can enter the name of a city and its weather data can be seen in the city.
I'm going to change this, so it seems to be about information the cities listed in the param. management environment without the need to enter the name of the city through the list you can select the name of the city.
I need to be in the user's environment to do it.
So need to change param in user environment. can you help?!

admin xml param :

```
<param name="location" type="list" default="Tehran" label="LOCATION" description="LOCATION_DESC">
               <option value="Tehran">Tehran</option>
            <option value="Karaj">Karaj</option>            
            <option value="Mashhad">Mashhad</option>            
            <option value="Shiraz">Shiraz</option>
            <option value="Tabriz">Tabriz</option></param>
```

using code in front :

```
<td><select name="location" label="LOCATION" description="LOCATION_DESC">
            <option value="Tehran" <?php if ($params->get('location') == "Tehran") echo "selected";echo $location ?> >Tehran</option>
            <option value="Karaj" <?php if ($params->get('location') == "Karaj") echo "selected"; ?> >Karaj</option>            
            <option value="Mashhad" <?php if ($params->get('location') == "Mashhad") echo "selected"; $params->get('location') = Mashhad; ?> >Mashhad</option>          
            <option value="Shiraz" <?php if ($params->get('location') == "Shiraz") echo "selected"; ?> >Shiraz</option>
            <option value="Tabriz" <?php if ($params->get('location') == "Tabriz") echo "selected"; ?> >Tabriz</option>
                            </select></td>
```

image :[http://photos.vne.ir/img/2a1d073d5ed3.jpg][1]

،To change the city needs to change is the Param, whether it is correct?

How changes in the $params->get('location') ?

```
$params->get('location') = value;
```

Comment: Out of all honesty, you don't want to be using a module where the user needs to input a field that manipulates the XML file. I would strongly recommend finding another weather extensions that suits your needs and allows user input via a form

Comment: I second what Lodder says. It would be better to customize the module to your needs. It cannot be done but also allowing guests to change params is a VERY bad idea for security. Create your own simple drop down and link it through jQuery/Javascript to change the country rather than through the params